# PostgreSQL: How do I split text string into slices based on a threshold value?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a sample data in my PostgreSQL database like follows:

```
ID       Thresh    array
(int)    (int)     (text)
1        171       61,201,20.0
2        89        59,119,9.0
```

Array exaplanation is as follows: In `61, 201, 20.0` the first `61` and second `201` are the `start` and end `values` of `array` range. While, `20.0` is the `mean` value of `array`. For each `ID`, I need to split `array range` into slices if it encounters threshold value `Thresh`. If it doesn't encounter the threshold value then output will be same. The expected output is as follows:

```
ID       Thresh    array
(int)    (int)     (text)
1        171       61,171,20.0,171,201,20.0
2        89        59,89,9.0,89,119,9.0
```

While, splitting the `array` the mean value for example `20.0` and `9.0` will remain the same. Can someone suggest me how could I split array range into slices?

Comment: Show us the code that you have tried so far, please. It might be more clear than your English explanation. Also, please add a tag for `python` or similar if it is OK to query the DB, process the text and report results. Constraining the solution to just SQL might be more constrictive than you desire.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have edited the tags anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the string to array, modify its elements (if necessary) and convert the array back to string:

```
with my_table(id, thresh, arr) as (
values
(1, 171, '61,201,20.0'),
(2, 89, '59,119,9.0')
)

select
    id, thresh,
    array_to_string(a, ',') as arr
from (
    select 
        id, thresh, 
        case 
            when thresh between a[1] and a[2] 
            then array[a[1], thresh, a[3], thresh, a[2], a[3]] 
            else a
        end as a
    from (
        select 
            id, thresh, 
            string_to_array(arr, ',')::float[] a
        from my_table
        ) s
    ) s;

 id | thresh |         arr          
----+--------+----------------------
  1 |    171 | 61,171,20,171,201,20
  2 |     89 | 59,89,9,89,119,9
(2 rows)
```